# Definition 7.8 of embedding in "General Topology" by Willard

Tags: general-topology

In the text "General Topology" by Willard, def. 7.8 says

> If X and Y are topological spaces, a function $f$ from X to Y is a *homeomorphism* iff $f$ is one-one, onto and continuous and $f^{-1}$ is also continuous. In this case, we say X and Y are *homeomorphic*. If $f$ is everything but onto, we call it an *embedding* of X into Y, and say that X is *embedded* in Y by $f$. Thus, X is embedded in Y by $f$ iff $f$ is a homeomorphism between X and some subspace of Y.

My question is regarding the phrase in the middle: "If $f$ is everything but onto". In such case, $f^{-1}$ is no longer a function, and then how would the earlier requirement "$f^{-1}$ is also continuous" apply?

Note that my question is not about the meaning of embedding, which has already been explained again in the last sentence in the paragraph and I find no confusion there.

My question is about how to interpret the phrase "If $f$ is everything but onto". One way I can think of is rephrasing it as something like (this is also like an elaboration of the last sentence in the original text):

> If $f$ is everything but onto, and the bijection $\hat{f}:X\rightarrow f[X]$ that has the same graph as $f$, where $f[X]$ is the image of $X$ under $f$ equipped with the subspace topology induced by $Y$, is a homeomorphism, we call it ...

but this seems adding too much additional stuff. I wonder if there is any more straightforward and natural way of fixing/interpreting the original text to justify the way it's written, or if the original text is indeed a little sloppy here.

Comment: You are right. Willard is imprecise. It seems that for a one-one $f$ he regards $f^{-1}$ as a function $f^{-1} : f(X) \to X$, but he should have mentioned it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation is correct. It is confirmed by the author who states that an embedding is an homeomorphism from $X$ onto $f[X]$.

Answer (score 1):

That's fine, although it's not necessary to go into graphs and all that, you can simply word it in terms of the rather common concept of "range restriction", like this:

> If $f$ is one-to-one and continuous, and if the range restriction $f : X \to f[X]$ has continuous inverse $f^{-1} : f[X] \to X$ with respect to the subspace topology on $f[X] \subset Y$, then we call $f$ an embedding.